# svnversion output but recursive over externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I am trying to identify local (not automated build server) builds of SVN projects with externals (and sub-externals) by their URL, revision, and dirty/clean status.  The overall result will simply be all clean or something somewhere is dirty, I do not care what is dirty.  Is such a program/script already handy?  Or must I be less lazy and write it myself...  (I have been unlazy enough to search a bit).  In short, a fancy version of `svnversion` which is aware of externals.

I have tried `svnversion`.  Here is a redacted copy from my Cygwin shell.

```
altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ svnversion
606

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ svn propget svn:externals
^/../the_canopen_library@223 libs/canopen

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ echo blue >> libs/canopen/wrapper/CANOpenGuard.c

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ svnversion
606

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ echo blue >> src/App_Main.c

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ svnversion
606M

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$ svnversion --version
svnversion, version 1.8.3 (r1516576)
   compiled Aug 30 2013, 11:03:40 on i686-pc-cygwin

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

altendky@ly /svn/myProject.clean
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to read `svnversion -h` and test WC with externals? I see - no, because presence or absence of exernals inside WC does change nothing in result

> The version identifier will be a single number if the working copy is
>   single revision, unmodified, not switched and with   a URL that
>   matches the TRAIL_URL argument.  If the working copy is unusual the
>   version identifier will be more complex

For clean checkout of repo-URL with externals inside

```
>dir /B
core_mod.txt
lib
```

(lib is directory-externals in foreign repo)

`svnversion` for the root of WC generates, as expected

```
>svnversion
7
```

In case of **any modifications** inside WC, which will destroy "vanilla" state, version identity will be more complex than pure single number:

`A[:B[MSP]]`

Comment: A lazy question gets a response from the lazy badger.  :]  But is this meant as an answer?  Yes, svnversion does what I want for a WC without externals but I need similar functionality against externals.  Even just an E indicator would be helpful.  (which really just means I should extend svnversion with the feature I want)

Comment: @altendky - **which** "similar functionality" **exactly**?! `svnversion` output *only* version

Comment: svnversion always outputs the version but also outputs indicators when the working copy is not clean (not _only_ the version).  I would like an indicator that would be triggered by a dirty/missing/wrong revision/mixed revision external.

Comment: @altendky - svnversion **do it**, because externals are part of WC

Comment: Have you actually seen it do what I want?  It does not for me (I tried it before posting), see the edited question.